# Warning: pdo_dummy::rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i tried changing all my MySQL queries in order to use PDO..

After changing, I have some few errors like this..when trying to add a new comment in file.php, annoying thing is the comment is added but this error comes as well..

```
Warning: pdo_dummy::rowCount() Your last query was unsuccessful and returned FALSE   
instead of a fetchable result. See pdo_error() to find out why. - caused by /home/user
/public_html/file.php, line 118, when calling pdo_affected_rows(); in /home/user
/public_html/includes/pdo_mysql.php on line 1068
```

**On line 118 in file.php**

```
if (pdo_affected_rows() == 1)
        show_error_msg(T_("COMPLETED"), T_("COMMENT_ADDED"), 0);
    else
        show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("UNABLE_TO_ADD_COMMENT"), 0);
```

**On Line 1068 in pdo_mysql.php**

```
function pdo_trigger_error($msg, $level=E_USER_NOTICE) {

 // locate source of last pdo_*() invocation
 foreach ((debug_backtrace()) as $src) {

    // skip any functions in the current file
    if (empty($src["file"])) {
       $src["file"] = "{main}";
       $src["line"] = "-";
    }
    if ($src["file"] != __FILE__) {
       $dir = dirname($src["file"]);
       $file = basename($src["file"]);
       $msg .= " - caused by $dir/<b>$file</b>, line <b>$src[line]</b>, when calling <a>$src[function]()</a>;";
       break;
    }
 }

 // pass on to actual error handler chain
 trigger_error($msg, (($level == 1<<14) && (PHP_VERSION < 5.3)) ? E_USER_NOTICE : $level);
}
```

I'm thinking this error occurs as a result of conflict but not sure...

```
trigger_error($msg, (($level == 1<<14) && (PHP_VERSION < 5.3)) ? E_USER_NOTICE : $level);
```

The complete pdo_mysql.php script is here [**Using PDO_MySQL**](http://fossil.include-once.org/upgradephp/artifact/43ab742241e5a3be43d31764dd333ba68e245360)
Thanks.....

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory. You performed a query and it failed. You can't access the results of a failed query.

Comment: Your functions don't seem to function. I would advise you to learn how to use PDO before attempting a wall of code.

Comment: Your link shows code for a `Procedural pdo_* interface mimicking mysql_* functions` which is not PDO. I advise you to forget about this  junk and use proper PDO.